# How to pipe data through. Error: has no method on

Tags: node.js, express

so I have data being passed along in req.body.fileData.

```
res.pipe(req.body.fileData)
  .pipe(base64.decode())
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(location));
```

This is failing on the first line with:

```
Blah blah has no method 'on'
    at ServerResponse.Stream.pipe
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

```
res.send(req.body.fileData)
  .pipe(etc).
```

Comment: Is this a solution to your question?